# "That didn't solve my problem" button

Tags: feature-request, duplicate-questions

When somebody raised a flag/close vote to close your question as duplicate, you see a button *"That solved my problem!"* and a link *"I will edit to explain how."* to edit your question. If you do the edit, this button will disappear (if I remember correctly). If you do not edit, there is no way to hide this button. Can we have a button "*That didn't solve my problem"* which would hide *"That solved my problem!"* and all this stuff? There are some cases when duplicate flags/votes are raised incorrectly and this stuff at the top of the question is annoying.

Comment: but if you know it isn't a dupe, you have to be able to explain why. If you can't in any other way but "no", it's not exactly convincing. Alternatively, you can just use uBlock and zap the element, but people can still vote to close regardless of your choice (unless you pick "That solved my problem", which hammers the question)

Comment: I would like to leave a comment explaining why my question is not a dupe, but I don't want to edit the question body. "It is not a dupe" is not relevant to the question body.

Comment: @Zoethetransgirl just to add - if you can't say anything other than "it's not a dupe" with no explanation, then how would *other people* be able to understand that and suggest a different solution?

Comment: @sanyash of course it's relevant. If you're able to leave a comment with *substance*, then you should be able to work it into the question body. Again, if you cannot say anything other than "No", then how would people know *why* it's a "No"? I see a lot of people who argue that it's not a dupe because superficially the question is different - it uses a different variable name than what they have in their code. Other times they maintain the dupe didn't work because they actually implemented it the wrong way. How do you differentiate between those and *actually* not being a dupe?

Comment: Oh... Of course I can explain in details why my question is not a dupe. But again, I don't want to add this information to the question body because somebody voted incorrectly.

Comment: An explanation on why a question is not a duplicate is most assuredly relevant to the question -- it says how your question differs from other questions about the same subject. If that's not relevant, I don't know what is...

Comment: @VLAZ please dont think like I am stupid. I **can** explain why my question is not a dupe.

Comment: @sanyash sorry for the confusion, but I'm not implying you're "stupid". I'm stating a fact - some people wrongfully contest dupes. It requires an actual explanation to see if the dupe target is correct or not. Of course it happens that some times people *do* vote for the incorrect dupe. When that happens, it's likely because the question is not clear enough, so an extra explanation of *why* there is a difference, will remove the ambiguity. So, it's absolutely relevant to edit the question with that information.

Comment: I see one of the most common reasons OPs resist dupes is that we are trying to be a general, canonical resource for programming knowledge, and thus dupes often point to general advice or information (NPE being the classic example), and OPs look at it and say “well what do I type into my source code to get the result I want???” Instead or applying their thoughtwork to use the general knowledge to apply it to their specific situation. It’s the same general disconnect between SO wanting to be a library and OPs wanting it to be a helpdesk.

Comment: @sanyash it seems like you are requesting feature strictly for yourself without consideration how it will be used by other users. People who ask question have generally very hard time to actually see what they asked - it is very hard to read post the same way as everyone else if one has a lot of context about the question... (even ignoring cases where wrong terminology completely changes the question). So ideally one would look at "possible duplicate" as "your question looks like asking about X even if you believe otherwise, please edit so it is clear that you need Y".

Comment: We *want* people to edit. That's why the system is designed as it is.

Comment: Okay. At least now we have this feature-request proposed and rejected by downvotes from community.

Comment: *because somebody voted incorrectly* - Is the issue that the close voter has already admitted that it was a mistake or is it that explaining why the dupe isn't relevant feels like adding noise to the post? If it's the former then you can ask them to retract their close vote.

Comment: @BSMP you are the first who understands me correctly. The second. Explanation why this question is not a dupe is noise imho. The place for it is comments.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, SO really wants you to edit the question and not dismiss other people opinions.

"[Possible] duplicate" does not mean "this ##$@$ elitists did not care to answer my question" but rather "the question *as written* already has answer on SO".  "As written" is very important part for SO visitors - whether once to answer question or to find answers to similar question of they own. It is very hard for the author of the question to see it in the same light as everyone else who don't have the same context for the question.

Ideally the author should look at the duplicate and think why the other question is considered duplicate - maybe you've used wrong terminology (i.e. in XML used "attribute" instead of "node"), maybe you want unconventional use case which no one can guess from question or you omitted large amount of context for the question. If such problem identified - editing the question should be trivial, otherwise commenting (possibly with @-ping to voters if possible) could be an option. In many cases an edit like "suggested duplicate {link} answers X while I'm looking for Y" is enough to clarify (and additionally it "shows research").

In very rare cases when suggested duplicate is completely random such "not a duplicate" button could be useful, but I don't think there is enough of those to justify the feature.

Comment: You all are thinking about 99% of cases where duplicate targets are correct. I was thinking about this 1% where they aren't. _In very rare cases when suggested duplicate is completely random such "not a duplicate" button could be useful, but I don't think there is enough of those to justify the feature._ - this.

Comment: @sanyash The issue is every OP who sees a “possible duplicate...” comment is 100% convinced they are in that 1%. And so your proposed feature would be abused. And in either case, the remedy is the same: edit your Q to acknowledge the dupe and explain why it doesn’t apply.

Answer (score 0):

This site is meant to *build a knowledge base from questions and answers*. For sure questions and thus askers are an important part of this site. *But* there is another very important group here. Answerers. Voting is a very powerful feature for *answerers* to focus on good questions (there are so many questions but a limited amount of answerers with limited time). For sure that we *help askers* is a good side effect, but *we are not a helpdesk*.

Thus we can't just let askers reopen questions that were closed by answerers for good reasons².

---

<sub>2: In the case that a duplicate is inappropriate (thats rare, but it happens - we're all humans), ping the ones voting in the comments - they are glad to reopen (if you have valid concerns)</sub>